# How to avoid Suspicious sign-in alerts from google?

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

I am developing a gtalk client. My server is hosted on amazon. My users access service on my server. my server sends requests (XMPP) to google.

Now, most of my users are facing issues related to  Suspicious sign-in alerts.

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use your user's username/password to authenticate. Instead, use OAuth 2.0:

https://developers.google.com/talk/jep_extensions/oauth

this should let Google understand that a legitimate application, not an interactive user (or scammer) is accessing the account.

Jay

Comment: Though this page talks about oauth for gtalk, however, on API page there is no way to grant privileges for talk app.

Comment: are you referring to the Google API Console? Older APIs that are not listed on the Console API page do not need to be explicitly turned on in the API Console.